# Call existing JS-Angular function using Selenium in Java

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium

I am new to selenium, I have a complex angularJS app with HTML 5, Once Page is loaded is browser, I want to execute the some exiting service javascript code using selenium js.executeScript(""). So far what I have found, we can execute our new code and will work as anonymous function . Please help me how can I locate and execute my angular service. The Java script file is loaded at the time of application load. 
Please help.
Thank you in advance
Krish